# Best way to model timeseries data in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to model a table with the following attributes:

User_id
Product_id
Timestamp

The table logs when users purchased products.
Modeling it in dynamo I added year,month, day as GSIs 
While partition key is user_id and timestamp is sorted_key
Is this a correct approach to allow time based queries?
There are two queries I am trying to optimize for:

1. Get products purchased by a user given a date range
2. Get users who purchased any products given a date range

Comment: Please tell more about the data.

Comment: Also tell us more about your query requirements. Table design should be designed to optimize for your query needs

Comment: Is this the only query that you want to make or are there other queries? How much data are you going to have?

Comment: @cody123 Updated with the query requirments

Comment: @TofigHasanov updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Query 1, it is enough that you have user_id as primary key and timestamp as a range key. You don't need any additional GSI for this query.

Query 2 is a bit more tricky.

You can certainly split time into periods like year, months, weeks, or days and use those as GSI (with timestamp as a sort key, so that you can tune queries to match your period exactly). However, it feels like this is going to be an expensive solution, with a risk of having hot keys (as all the write throughput will go into same year/month/day at any given time).

Instead, for query 2 I would recommend using a different approach: you can create a single GSI, with random shard number between 1 and N as a primary key and timestamp as a sort key. Pick N (ex: 8), based on your throughput requirements, and you can always increase it later. Now, whenever you add a new record, assign it a random shard number between 1 and N. And whenever you need to get all purchases between two timestamps, you make N parallel queries and then merge results.